# Conditional formatting levels

Tags: python-3.1

I am teaching myself python and I know formatting is critical for but I can' figure out how to make the formatting work for a conditional statement.  When using an if statement I can't get the else to line up at the same level as the if.  The else comes out at the same level as the "true" conditional.  If I backspace (or use a shift tab) then the else goes to the far left without the >>>.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use some IDE like atom.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using IDLE but gave up.  Works just fine if I directly edit/create a file.